# the field is too small to accept the data you wanted to add. try inserting or pasting less data

Tags: ms-access-2007

```
SELECT net1.hhid, net1.prod_price, net2.seed, net3.lph_labour, net4.crop_labour, net5.fer_cost, net6.pes_cost, net7.seed_labour, net8.irr_cost,

(net2.seed+net3.lph_labour+net4.crop_labour+net5.fer_cost+net6.pes_cost+net7.seed_labour+net8.irr_cost) AS cost,

 (net1.prod_price-cost) AS net_profit

FROM net1, net2, net3, net4, net5, net6, net7, net8

WHERE net1.hhid=net2.hhid And net1.hhid=net3.hhid And net1.hhid=net4.hhid And net1.hhid=net5.hhid And net1.hhid=net6.hhid And net1.hhid=net7.hhid And net1.hhid=net8.hhid And net1.country=net2.country And net1.country=net3.country And net1.country=net4.country And net1.country=net5.country And net1.country=net6.country And net1.country=net7.country And net1.country=net8.country;
```

The error message states that the

> field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. try inserting or pasting less data

What is wrong with my code? I need to add the column vales of net1 to 8 queries, in which there hhid and country should be equal.

Comment: Toot many tables with no `JOIN`. Looks to me there is more to the problem. Your solution is **Normalization**

Comment: how do I normalize ? im sorry but its been just 3 months since I started using access or creating my own database queries